Power of a point proof question
I’m trying to follow this proof:
proof
Specifically this part:
The parameters  $t_1,t_2$ of possible common points of line  $g: \vec x=\vec p+t\vec v$ (through $P$) and circle $c$ can be determined by inserting the parametric equation into the circle's equation:
:$(\vec p+t\vec v)^2-r^2=0 \quad  \rightarrow \quad
t^2+2t\;\vec p\cdot\vec v +\vec p^2-r^2=0 \ .$
Can anyone explain this further? I don’t understand why the parametric equation of a line is being substituted into the equation for a circle.
I already asked a question to clarify the first part:
question to clarify circle part

"I don’t understand why the parametric equation of a line is being substituted into the equation for a circle." That's how you intersect two curves: You want a point that is in both curves, so it need so satisfy both equations. A typical way to solve a system of two equation is to solve for one variable in one of the equations (in this case you already have the equation of the line solved for $x$) and substitute the variable in the other equation.

If you are banging your head on learning from Wikipedia (not surprising, it's not meant to teach), I'd suggest either listening to someone teach about it, or reading a textbook . Here is a video lecture on power of a point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMMOVxiXak8

@jjagmath you have the answer

$r$ is the constant scalar geometric mean of all segment vector lengths through P. Start by squaring algebraically and then take the dot product
$$(\vec p + t \vec v )\cdot (\vec p + t \vec v)=r^2  $$
$$=(\vec p \cdot   \vec p ) + 2 t\vec p  \vec v + (t\vec v \cdot t \vec v) =r^2 $$
$$=(\vec p \cdot   \vec p ) + 2 t\vec p  \vec v + (t\vec v \cdot t \vec v)=r^2  $$
$$=(\vec p ^2) + 2 t\vec p  \vec v + (t^2 1)=r^2  $$
with the last being dot product of two unit vectors
